# Finding Subdirectories in Python

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, subdirectory

I want to find subdirectories in Python for a personal project, with a catch. I imagine I'd use something like os.walk(), but every instance I can find involving it uses a predefined string with the location of the folder to look at. For example, this code

```
import os
 
rootdir = 'path/to/dir'
for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for subdir in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(rootdir, subdir))
```

involves setting a defined rootdir. I do not want this. Instead, I want to just look in the file the code is being run at. If I run the code.py in a c:/users/me/ it should search all subdirectories of that location. If I move the code to another folder, it should search the subdirectories of that folder. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to use `os.getcwd()` as rootdir.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts can see their their own filename in the `__file__` attribute. You can use that to find the script's directory and make that the basis of the search.

```
import os
root = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]
print(root)
for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for subdir in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(rootdir, subdir))
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.